# Valores únicos en una tabla

Tags: python

Tengo una tabla 1, `full_1`, con dos columnas, **país** y **moneda** (para un país una moneda) y aparte tengo otra tabla 2, `df_str_country`, que también tiene estas dos columnas (para un mismo país más de una moneda) y quiero que cuando las relacione solo me de datos de la primera columna. Es decir, me deje solo la línea de la tabla 2 donde aparece ese país con esa moneda.

Estoy utilizando lo siguiente pero no me da bien

```
df_str = df_str_country[(df_str_country['country'].isin(full_1['country'].unique())) & (df_str_country['local currency'].isin(full_1['local currency'].unique()))].copy()
```

porque lo que hace es cogerme todos aquellos países que aparecen en la tabla `full_1` y me pone todas las monedas que encuentra en `full_1` independientemente del país.

Es decir, si en la tabla `full_1` yo tengo:

```
País              Moneda
Argentina          ARS
España             EUR
```

Lo que me está haciendo para la tabla 2 es:

```
País              Moneda
Argentina          ARS
Argentina          EUR
```

no se si me he explicado correctamente

Muchas gracias a todos
Fran

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes incluir algunas líneas de tu `dataframe` como texto? Y ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo de cuál sería el comportamiento esperado? No es muy claro lo que pides, ¿Sería algo como eliminar las filas que son iguales entre el primer y segundo `dataframe`?

Comment: buenas y muchas gracias, no se si te sirve el ejemplo que te he puesto. un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que buscas llama `merge` `dataframes` y se hace con [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Como no pusiste los datos de tu `dataframe` cree un ejemplo genérico y tendrás que adaptarlo a tus datos

Tenemos dos `dataframes` de la siguiente forma:

```
#df1
    País            Moneda  tipo de cambio
0   Argentina       ARS     0,7
1   España          EUR     1
2   Estados Unidos  USD     0,8

#df2
    País        Moneda  Unidades
0   Argentina   ARS     2
1   Argentina   EUR     5
2   Argentina   USD     7
3   España      GBP     2
4   España      EUR     10
```

Y el resultado esperado es poder poner los valores de la columna "Unidades" en el primer `dataframe` siempre y cuando País y Moneda coincidan

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2[['País', 'Moneda', 'Unidades']], on=['País', 'Moneda'], how="inner")
```

Al imprimir `df3` obtenemos:

```
    País        Moneda  tipo de cambio  Unidades
0   Argentina   ARS     0,7             2
1   España      EUR     1               10
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, pero si en el df2 tengo muchas más variables para añadir tengo que ponerlas todas o poniendo df1.merge(df2, on=['Pais','Moneda'], how = 'inner') me valdría? muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Buen día, eso ya te quedaría de tarea, recuerda que parte de la cultura de Stack Overflow es mostrar un esfuerzo por resolver tus preguntas, podrías empezar intentando tal como está. Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: perdona mi ignoracía, como la acepto?

Comment: @FranMilla, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y a familiarizarte con las normas de la comunidad. Para aceptar una respuesta del lado izquierdo de cada respuesta hay unas flechas en medio un `check mark` para aceptarla.